# Apache Beam/Dataflow joins on Big Query dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Below is a code snippet, for doing join on 2 tables say from BigQuery. But that does a full Outer join.
If I am looking to do Left/Right/Inner join, what is the best way of doing?
Is converting the PCollection into PCollection, and then make use of Beam join library(https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html) to do left/right/outer is a right approach ?? Or does CoGbkResult provide options of different joins?

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

// Create tuple tags for the value types in each collection.
final TupleTag<TableRow> table1Tag = new TupleTag<>();
final TupleTag<TableRow> table2Tag = new TupleTag<>();

// Transform for keying table rows by session_id and cookie_id
WithKeys<String, TableRow> sessionAndCookieKeys = WithKeys.of(
    (TableRow row) ->
        String.format("%s#%s",
            row.get("session_id"),
            row.get("cookie_id")))
    .withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.strings());

/*
 * Steps:
 *  1) Read table 1's rows
 *  2) Read table 2's rows
 *  3) Map each row to a composite key
 *  4) Join on the composite key
 *  5) Process the results
 */
PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> table1Rows = pipeline
    .apply(
        "ReadTable1",
        BigQueryIO
            .readTableRows()
            .from(options.getTable1()))
    .apply("WithKeys", sessionAndCookieKeys);

PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> table2Rows = pipeline
    .apply(
        "ReadTable2",
        BigQueryIO
            .readTableRows()
            .from(options.getTable2()))
    .apply("WithKeys", sessionAndCookieKeys);

//Merge collection values into a CoGbkResult collection
PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResult = KeyedPCollectionTuple
    .of(table1Tag, table1Rows)
    .and(table2Tag, table2Rows)
    .apply("JoinOnSessionAndCookie", CoGroupByKey.create());

// Process the results
coGbkResult.apply(
    "ProcessResults", 
    ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, Object>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        // Do something here
      }
    }));
```

Comment: why are you doing a join outside BQ - when you could perform it inside BQ?

Comment: There are so many transformations to be done involving about 15 tables with Big Data to finally end up populating 3 other tables. I know, i can also make use of VIEW to join tables, And i was not sure how feasible it is going to be joining all those tables. So, I was also exploring the transformation logic which could be done through Dataflow to use it to an extent. Do you recommend those kind of logics to be done purely as part of DDL joins and Views?

Comment: It all depends in the case, but generally speaking anything you can run inside BigQuery, you should run inside BigQuery for speed and costs reasons

Comment: What Felipe said. Unless you absolutely must do your work outside of BigQuery, then stay in SQL and leverage the power and speed of BigQuery. It will pay dividends. I've rarely found a use case where a transformation/workload couldn't be done directly in BigQuery.

Comment: My usecase involves hourly run. And each run of a pipeline has dependancies using multiple VIEWs. I would want a manipulated resultset of a View to be inserted into a table, then again would want to call a different view based which also queries the inserted table. I am hoping this pipeline order can be done in Dataflow. But majority of the joins i am only going to make use of the Views. Doing inside BigQuery directly, I see it as a manual effort, where I would want automate the complete flow.

Comment: I'm facing similar issues, I need to do a join outside of BigQuery because bigquery supports maximum of 10000 columns per table, but the tables I need to join is more than 10000 columns. Does anyone has a working snippets of reading tables from bq and join them? I tried using Join library but it's just too complex, then I tried using Beam SQL but couldn't find an easy way to convert AvroGenericRecord to Row..